# Category Page is broken after import or update the product and category in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

Category Page is broken after import or update the product or category. But after run the reindex, cache flush command and refresh the browser cache, it works well.

Cron job is run correctly. Please let me know why this is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

It is very vague information you gave. You need to be specific and give proper detail. After every catalog import your catalog data is changed.  You need to reindex and flush the cache after every catalog import.